# How to create a tablet UI with multiple ContentPages on one screen at the same time with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: user-interface, android-fragments, uisplitviewcontroller, tablet, xamarin.forms

I want to design a `UI` for tablets (`Android` & `iOS`) with `Xamarin.Forms` where I want to have multiple `ContentPages` on one screen. I know how to achieve this for `Android` by using `Fragments` (afaik for `iOS` it's `UISplitViewController`).

How can I achieve this with `Xamarin.Forms`?

P.s. I definitely don't want a `TabbedPage`!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you can't put multiple ContentPage items on the screen, at least not within the out-of-the-box Xamarin.Forms.

You can, however, put multiple ContentView items on the screen and you can reuse the ContentView items in stand-alone pages as well.

Essentially you can describe what you'd want to see on a single page as a ContentView and then make a page that just includes that

PhotoItem.xaml:

```
<ContentView>
   <Grid>
     <Image Source="{Binding MyImageSource}"/>
   </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

PhotoBucket.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns:local="namespace;assembly">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="View">
     <OnIdiom.Phone>
       <ListView>
          ... on list item tap do Navigation.PushAsync(new PhotoItemPage{BindingContext = itemTapped} );
       </ListView>
      </OnIdiom.Phone>
     <OnIdiom.Tablet>
       <Grid> // Add two columns
         <ListView Grid.Column="0">
            ... on list item tap do PhotoItem.BindingContext = itemTapped
         </ListView>
         <local:PhotoItem Grid.Column="1"/>
      </OnIdiom.Tablet>
    </OnIdiom>
  </ContentPage.Content> 
</ContentPage>
```

PhotoItemPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns:local="namespace;assembly">
   <local:PhotoItem>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: The main problem with such an approach is that you need to implement navigation yourself and can't rely on NavigationPage, MasterDetailPage etc.

Comment: I really don't understand this statement - you will be using whatever pages you need to, just the views inside will be encapsulated into your own custom views. To trigger navigation from within a custom view expose either a command or an event and handle it inside the page

Comment: When using native APIs I would use Fragments on Android and ViewControllers on iOS to modularize my code and benefit from the build in mechanisms (back stack, life cycle, etc.). Fragments/ViewControllers can be placed side by side, and Xamarin Pages use these for their native implementations so technically it should also be possible to place two Pages side by side (for example a CarouselPage and a ContentPage).

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple pages, use content views for it. Or custom renderers

Comment: Well... there is the MasterDetailPage which has two ContentPages. At least internally there must be a concept of "pages inside of pages".