# Inject views in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to inject platform specific views into shared pages?
Say I have a TabbedPage in my shared project, and I would like to inject a Page/View into it that uses the platform specific 2D drawing features, how would this best be solved?

Comment: check my answer to another user, not sure if that's what you're asking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075125/how-to-create-a-tablet-ui-with-multiple-contentpages-on-one-screen-at-the-same-t/25081737#25081737

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **ContentPage** you can add your own custom view control, to which you can then implement **Custom Renderers** - one for each platform from this shared view.

Its from within the **Custom Renderers** classes where you can then access all the native APIs such like overriding the **OnDraw(canvas canvas)** and do your custom 2D drawing on Android etc.

When you mention *Page/View*, I am going to assume you are really meaning *View*, as I don't believe its possible to render a **ContentPage** within an existing **ContentPage**.

Comment: It is now possible to add native views directly to the xamarin.forms layout controls. In the case of shared projects, this can be #ifdef-ed, for PCLs some sort of dependency service is required. Should be a bit easier than maintaining custom renderers for most cases where you just need to embed one native control as is