# Xamarin.Forms Tablet and Phone

Tags: xamarin.forms

Has anyone seen Xamarin.Forms examples for code that supports both tablet and phone UIs without doing dependency injection to fragments?

I would like to make use of the screen space, and I have built the entire application thus far with a ContentView -> ViewModel architecture but I cannot seem to find any example Xamarin.Forms code dealing specifically with universal UIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to create a tablet UI with multiple ContentPages on one screen at the same time with Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075125/how-to-create-a-tablet-ui-with-multiple-contentpages-on-one-screen-at-the-same-t/25081737#25081737)

The gist of it is to create `ContentView`-based UI implementations and then decide if you'd show them wrapped inside a ContentPage by themselves (on a phone) or show two or more of them together in a single ContentPage (on a tablet).

You can also leverage `[OnPlatform][1]` to choose between the two in a declarative manner.

Comment: This is what I was doing. The part I was missing was examples of actual implementation. I guess I will add some to a git. Thanks.